# How to select multiple Faces (Blender 2.80.0 Beta)?

Tags: python, scripting

[image]

Is it possible to select all the faces according to the pattern of the red dots?

Comment: Select the whole row of faces and do "checker deselect"

Comment: In this case, it looks like Shift-G > 'Select Similar' > 'Area'

Comment: So, is this about editing (as your post indicates) or is it a Python problem (according to your tags)?